# Excel 2016: Pulling data from numerous different tables to one master table

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a large workbook with many sheets, each having tables in them. I am attempting to use a formula to pull data from choice columns within those tables into a master table. Not all of the rows in the column will have data and I want it to only pull the data.

For example:

```
Master Table         T1ChoiceCol     T2ChoiceCol       T3ChoiceCol
aa123                aa123           bb256 
aa234                                bb656             xx321
bb256
bc656                aa234                             xy456
xx321
xy456                                                  xb124
xb124
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Power Query` or `VBA` should be the right approach here, instead of `Excel Formulas`. Not suggesting with formulas, because it may slow down the `Excel Engine` process. May be someone has a better alternative, however i see the example data posted is incomplete and insufficient. Also please post what you have tried/attempted any debugging details. But request to avoid `INDIRECT()` functions which is a volatile one, and usually not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Mayukh, use Power Query.

1. In a new workbook, go to the Data tab, and Get Data from an Excel Workbook and select your workbook with many tables.
2. In the Navigator window, check `Select multiple items` and select all tables that you want to retrieve data from.
3. Click `Transform Data`.
4. Complete any data cleaning, including keeping only the column(s) you want to append, for each table.
5. Rename all columns that you want to append to have the same column names.
6. In the Power Query Editor ribbon, choose `Append Queries as New` and select the `Three or more tables` radio button, then add all the tables you want to append, and finally click OK.
7. Remove any blank rows.
8. Click `Close and Load` to have appended or unioned result populate in a new worksheet.